# Google Apps Script Conditional If/Else If Statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got this script below but it keeps returning the incorrect information. For instance, even though the "urgency" may equal "medium", it returns the "critical" result.

```
var initialcontact;
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
var urgency = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Urgency")).getValue();
if (urgency = "Critical") {initialcontact = "1 hour";}
else if (urgency = "High") {initialcontact = "4 hours";}
else if (urgency = "Medium") {initialcontact = "1 day";}
else if (urgency = "Low") {initialcontact = "3 days";}
```

Comment: Presumably, the script you're using started out as the [Help Desk tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial). If so, it would be helpful to others for you to include that in the question - it gives background that may help resolve problems, and gives credit to the original authors.

Comment: I didn't begin with the Help Desk tutorial, but when I found it I did take parts from it...didn't think to include that. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `==` for comparing , not `=`

`if (urgency == "Critical")`

and so on..

Comment: Ok, I made that change but it is now coming back as "undefined"

Comment: Which variable is returning `undefined` ? Please also post the sample spreadsheet data

Comment: The initialcontact variable is returning as undefined in the spreadsheet...almost as if urgency = undefined but it doesn't. The sample is that I have a column with the listed "Urgency", for example "High", and then in the column "Initial Contact" I want it to return a variable accordingly, so if urgency was high, it would return "4 hours".

Comment: Did you change all 4 comparisons to `==`?

Comment: In addition to what Fred says, add a Logger.log() to print out the value of `urgency` . This is a very simple script and there is nothing else that can go wrong.