# if else not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote the small script show below that creates an `MS Word` document from `Google Sheets` data.

I added an `if-else` statement to prevent the script from creating a document for every row, from the beginning; however, the script only runs the code in the `else` condition. Please help me find where I'm going wrong.

```
function createDocFromSheet() {
    // get template file id:
    var templateid = "1yi0zKDyPYB2yL2-OFOp-lAUKXHmJaJjm0iKLg5uhjyU";
    // folder name of where to put completed diaries:
    var FOLDER_NAME = "0B8tUkeXcIHUuMXZEcDU0OXRsVTQ";
    // get the data from an individual user:
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    for (var row = 2; row <=data.length; row++) {
        var roll = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
        var studentName = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
        var fatherName = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
        var dob = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
        var transID = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
        var email = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
        var status = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();

        if (status = null) {
            //creating document
            var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(roll).getId();
            var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
            var body = doc.getBody();
            body.replaceText("<roll-no>", roll);
            body.replaceText("<student-name>", studentName);
            body.replaceText("<father’s-name>", fatherName);
            body.replaceText("<dob>", dob);
            body.replaceText("<trans-id>", transID);
            doc.saveAndClose();
        }
        else {
            Logger.log("status not null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script Conditional If/Else If Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404002/google-apps-script-conditional-if-else-if-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if (status === null){
```

Or even

```
if (status == null) {
```

Which may be the better option as I am thinking about it.
One = is not enough

Comment: Tried with both. It is still running else statement.

Comment: Worked! Replaced with == " ". Thank you.

Comment: So your cell you are testig with has a space in it? Note that some formulas will return an empty text item as well.  Such as `=IF(true_test, "", 0)`  which is better written as `=IF(true_test, ,0)`  as the second variation leave the cell as blank.